# Discord DiceParser (By RoliSteam/KDE?): ceil() function syntax needed (need to "round up" an average)

Tags: dice, rolisteam

[DiceParser "Full Documentation" (supposedly)](https://invent.kde.org/rolisteam/rolisteam-diceparser/-/blob/master/HelpMe.md)

Thought someone may know this, because I'm out of ideas. At this point...

**Goal:** Get an average and round up. (In programming, it's usually called something like "math ceiling" or "ceil" -- floor being rounding down).

So, I've tried the following:

*average of 4d4, count how many odd rolls there are, add +1 if an odd number of odd rolls (mathematically, this made sense to me at the time... don't know why...)*

```
2;6-$1;($2)D4;$3/4;$3|4;$3c[%2=1];$6i:[=1|=3]{$5+1}{$5+0};
```

*raw and rounded down average of 4d4, if raw is larger than rounded down, add +1 to rounded down*

```
2;6-$1;($2)D4;$3/4;$3|4;$4i[>$5]{$5+1}{$5+0};
```

*raw and rounded down average of 4d4, of raw and rounded down, keep the highest and if the highest is greater than the raw average, add +1 to rounded down*

```
2;6-$1;($2)D4;$3/4;$3|4;[$4,$5]k1;$6i[>$5]{$5+1}{$5+0};
```

I've tried these sytanxes every which way I can think of... if anyone has any idea, please help.

Also... if someone can explain what the documentation means by "Scalar" (not just a guess off the top of your head, because I've read several definitions already--I'm just not sure what *they* mean by it in the context of DiceParser), that'd be great--it may lead me to an answer for the above.

Answer (score 7):

For positive integers you can use a floor-division (which most programming languages, including DiceParser, use for division of positive integers) to implement a ceiling-division using the following identity:

$$
\left\lceil \frac{n}{d} \right\rceil = \left\lfloor \frac{n + d - 1}{d} \right\rfloor
$$

In this case the numerator \$n\$ is the sum rolled on the 4d4 and \$d\$ is the number of dice (4).

As for "scalar" they probably mean a result that is a single number (e.g. the sum of some dice), as opposed to a list of individual die rolls.

Comment: see "answer" below

Comment: while i appreciate your help, i still don't think that sounds right, because from what you are claiming, both sides of the equal sign SHOULD be actually equal and (from what i've extrapolated from your previous comment on the "answer" (response) i provided earlier) left side is the floor-division, which makes the right side the ceiling division. If all true, then simplifying the equation should still keep the identity true, but instead i come up with this: n = n + d -1 ..... or rather 0 = d - 1. d then can only be one value (instead of being able to put any values in)... am i misunderstanding?

Comment: The left side is the ceiling-division. You can't simplify fractions through a floor or ceiling operation -- that's the entire reason we're rounding in the first place.

Comment: i see... if i understand correctly then ceiling(n/d) = floor((n+d-1)/d). is this correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but... that also doesn't make sense, because essentially what you're claiming is that ("Scalar"÷"Number of Dice Rolled") is what this equation comes down to for ceiling. However, that literally just gets me a raw average, with decimal, if a remainder. Ex. 4D4, result 13. This would literally be ceil(13/4) = 3.25, but 3.25 rounded up is not 3.25. Rounded up would be 4. What the equation seems to get me is exactly where I already am: an average of a number set.

Maybe I didn't explain the question right? Please, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: The right side of the equation is floor((13 + 4 - 1) / 4) = floor(16 / 4) = 4 = ceil(13 / 4) as desired.

Comment: i get it now... gonna run some tests to see it it works. thanks for all the clarifications, it is all much appreciated.